# Coloring a cell based on the text of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba macro that runs and then the user has a column where they manually enter values from a dropdown after the output is sheet is created. I need the code to highlight the first cell of the row to a specific color based on the text.

```
For PoleRow = 14 To lastrow + 12
If Cells(PoleRow, 27) = "Simple" Then
   Cells(PoleRow, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(51, 102, 255)
End If
```

Currently what it is doing right now, is not working. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use conditional formatting for this?

Comment: Can we see the full code? What isn't working? Is it throwing an error code, or just not coloring? I would like to see how you declare `lastrow` and `PoleRow`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad how would i do conditional formatting? use the IF formula? I dont think ive ever done an IF statement in this kind of situation.

Comment: The most likely reason why your code doesn't seem working (although it might do, unless you are actually getting error messages) is because when you refer to cells like `Cells(PoleRow, 27)` then you are referencing `Activesheet.Cells(PoleRow, 27)` which may not be the WorkSheet you mean to test and colour by `If Cells(PoleRow, 27) = "Simple" Then` so the code inside the `If` statement may not get executed, or if it did it may colour a cell on a different sheet then what your are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

1. Highlight the range you want to have format based on the text
2. Select `Conditional Formatting` under the `Home` tab in the ribbon.
3. Select `New Rule` then Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
4. Input `=[cell reference unlocked]="Simple"`
5. Click `Format` and choose the color you want then hit `OK`

For Cell Reference Unlocked, just click the cell in the same row as your active highlighted range, but make sure there's no $'s in the reference.

Answer (score 0):

If You declared variables You are using the code is fine, just `Interior.Color` not getting this `RGB()`. Try with `vbBlue` or `Interior.ColorIndex`. My example is working:

```
Sub test()
Dim PoleRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

'for example
lastRow = 20

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For PoleRow = 14 To lastRow + 12
        If .Cells(PoleRow, 27) = "Simple" Then
            .Cells(PoleRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbBlue
            '.Cells(PoleRow,1).Interior.Colorindex = 5
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```