# Conditional Formatting - Changing cell color based on another cells text

Tags: excel, vba

Currently trying to debug my code. I want the first cell of the row to change a specific color based on the text in a cell in the same row. The text that is conditional is based in a drop-down list that the user manually inputs when the macro gets done running.

```
    For polerow = 14 To lastrow + 12
        If Cells(polerow, 27).Value = "Simple" Then
            Cells(polerow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            '.Cells(PoleRow,1).Interior.Colorindex = 5
        End If
    Next
```

I basically am trying to write something in formula format. The text that is conditional is "Simple". Thanks!

Comment: @MarkS. Kind of my thinking, but just the task i was given

Comment: This is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808548/coloring-a-cell-based-on-the-text-of-another-cell/57808640#57808640)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coloring a cell based on the text of another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808548/coloring-a-cell-based-on-the-text-of-another-cell)

Comment: @MarkS. it's not a "possible" duplicate, it's the exact same question. bear21 asked that one as well, apparently he didn't like your answer.

Comment: Can you show more of your code.  And please explain `I basically am trying to write something in formula format` are you trying to do this through a UDF called from the sheet?

Comment: @MilesFett the second one was system generated from the flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is you have not set the `lastrow`, you also need to identify the workbook and sheet references.

```
Dim cel As Range, lastrow As Long

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count 'sets the number of used rows

    'loop through each cell in Col27 from row 14 to the lastrow + 12 
    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA14:AA" & lastrow + 12)             
        If cel.Value = "Simple" Then 'test cell value for condition
            cel.Offset(, -26).Interior.ColorIndex = 5 'if condition is met then offset to first cell in row and color
        End If
    Next cel 'loop to next cell
```